# Selecting variable value in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a userform for case auditing that randomly selects a case #, displays it in a label on the form and shows neighboring cell data in text boxes on the same form via Vlookup (that part works fine). I added two buttons that allow the user to color coat the case # whether it was good or bad. How can i get it to find the cell where the randomly selected case # is and then coat that cell based on whether the good or bad button was selected?

```
Private Sub btnRandom_Click()
Dim x As Variant

lblText.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.range("A2:A502"), WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 501))

x = lblText.Caption

txtQuestion.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheet1.range("A1:M502"), 8, False)

txtSolution.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheet1.range("A1:M502"), 12, False)

End Sub
```

The above code does not run until i hit the Button labeled random.

Comment: Why not just store the result of `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 501)`?

Comment: Hey Ben, I am super new to VBA. I think I know what you mean, but not really, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find` method while work.

For example, this will color the cell red.

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:A502").Find(x,lookat:=xlWhole).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
```

As a note, it's best practice to *test that the instance is actually found* before directly working with it. But since you already know the instance will be there since you obtain in your lookup before, I have skipped that part.

Comment: Hi Scott, I am a little new to this, would that line of code go under the sub for "Bad" button? If so, wouldnt the X variable not get passed over because it is a local variable?

Comment: Update, I got it to work! Mostly thanks to your input, Scott. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad you got it working @ErikZometa. If someone has answered your question, it's best practice here to [accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

For all those that are curious, this is what ended up working for me:

```
Private Sub btnRandom_Click()

Dim x As Variant

lblText.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.range("A2:A502"), WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 501))

x = lblText.Caption

txtQuestion.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheet1.range("A1:M502"), 8, False)

txtSolution.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheet1.range("A1:M502"), 12, False)

Sheet1.range("A2:A502").Find(x, lookat:=xlWhole).Select

End Sub


Private Sub btnBad_Click()

ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End Sub
```